# Linq to Entities: Nested SelectMany returns whatever it wants

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to select custom type from my domain object set and noticed very strange EF behavior. I can figure out that exactly and why that's happening at all. So I have:

```
public class Person 
{ 
    public IList<Device> Devices { get; set; } 
}
public class Device  
{ 
    public DeviceConfiguration DeviceConfiguration  { get; set; } 
}
public class DeviceConfiguration 
{ 
    public IList<DeviceFeature> DeviceFeatures { get; set; } 
}
public class DeviceFeature 
{ 
    public DeviceFeatureType DeviceFeatureType  { get; set; } 
}
```

And I want to select a custom type from `Persons` set:

```
var personDTOs = persons.Select(x => 
    new PersonDTO 
    { 
        Devices = x.Devices, 
        DeviceFeatures = x.Devices.SelectMany(y => y.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceFeatures ) 
    });
```

Problem there is that `DeviceFeatures` populated with some random entries even when that `Person` doesn't have ANY `Devices`

Any thoughts why that is happening?

**Update 1:**

One significant thing that I forgot to mention is that `personDTOs` after are sorted and paged (`OrderBy, Skip, Take, ToList`) and these "random" DeviceFeatures included only after that. But if I select problematic entry before these action I can see everything is as expected. There something wrong with delayed execution and/or selecting custom type, but I cant understand what exactly and what is proper way of doing this kind of selects

Comment: Could you elaborate on *"random entries"*? Are they instances of `Device`, `null` values or something else?

Comment: @James it is DeviceFeature. Single record of DeviceFeature which is cannot be related to current person because person doesn't have any devices.

Comment: given `SelectMany` uses delayed execution, if you call `ToList` after it does it give you what you want?

Comment: Can you post generated SQL?

Comment: @James ToList will not work as it will not be able to translate into a store expression

Comment: @Vladimirs so that's probably because you are trying to do a nested select (`y.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceFeatures`) which can't be translated into SQL. So if you did `DeviceFeatures = x.Devices.SelectMany(x => x.DeviceConfiguration.SelectMany(y => y.DeviceFeatures))` does it work?

Comment: @James I can't do that because DeviceConfiguration has a List but not a List of List so DeviceConfiguration.SelectMany(y => y.DeviceFeatures) will not compiles

Comment: if I will do 'x.Devices.Any() ? x.Devices.SelectMany(y => y.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceFeatures ) : null' that it works ok.. But can't understand what it attempt to insert something irrelevant

Comment: @Vladimirs well just change that to `x.Devices.SelectMany(y => y.DeviceConfiguration.Select(y => y.DeviceFeatures))`. As to the reason why it's putting random stuff in there, can't say I know for sure. Possibly a bug with the LINQ provider, you should definitely post the generated SQL as @Dennis suggested.

Comment: @James I can't do that either because in that context y.DeviceConfiguration is DeviceConfiguration but not a list. So I can access to DeviceConfiguration properties only

Comment: Will try x.Devices.Select(y => y.DeviceConfiguration).Select(y => y.DeviceFeatures) in a moment

Comment: @Vladimirs yeah, that makes sense, I got a bit confused as to what was a list and what was a property! Although, there are ways to get your original query to work with the `ToList` call but it would require using `AsEnumerable` which would mean running the nested select in memory.

Comment: @James Yeah but I didn't wanted to run it in memory =(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48472/discussion-between-vladimirs-and-james)

Comment: What type has `persons`?

Comment: @James tried x.Devices.Select(y => y.DeviceConfiguration).SelectMany(y => y.DeviceFeatures) (last should be SelectMany instead of just Select) but it appears to be the same. Found out that x.Devices.DefaultIfEmpty().SelectMany(y => y.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceFeatures).DefaultIfEmpty() works correct but that doesn't work for LINQ to Objects

Comment: @Slauma IQueriable<Person>

Comment: And how do you retrieve `persons` from a `context.DbSet<T>` (or `ObjectSet<T>`)?

Comment: @Slauma context.Set<Person>().AsNoTracking()

Comment: What is the database and LINQ provider you are using?

Comment: Alright, thanks for everybody efforts I will stick with weird `x.Devices.Any() ? x.Devices.SelectMany(y => y.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceFeatures ) : null` and will try to go on living without understanding what this EF does on it's own. However life will never be the same =(

Comment: @Slauma database is SQL server 2008 and provider I don't know where to find it probably default one. Please do not waste more time on that. Just suggest me please should I delete that ticket?

Comment: I would write your workaround as your own answer below. Maybe someone from EF dev team will see it and confirm it's a bug or someone will provide an explanation. (It would be the first time that I see a bug in the LINQ provider for SQL Server.) However, to make the problem reproducable for somebody else the *full* LINQ query you are using would be helpful - including the `AsNoTracking`, the `OrderBy`, `Skip`, `Take`, etc. One of these details could matter...